# Best way to manage docker containers with supervisord

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, docker

I have to setup "dockerized" environments (integration, qa and production) on the **same** server (client's requirement). Each environment will be composed as follow:

- rabbitmq
- celery
- flower
- python 3 based application called "A" (specific branch per
  environment)

Over them, jenkins will handle the deployment based on CI.

Using set of containers per environment sounds like the best approach.

But now I need, process manager to run and supervise all of them:

- 3 rabbit containers,
- 3 celery/flower containers,
- 3 "A" containers,
- 1 jenkins containers.

Supervisord seem to be the best choice, but during my tests, i'm not able to "properly" restart a container. Here a snippet of the supervisord.conf

```
[program:docker-rabbit]
command=/usr/bin/docker run -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 tutum/rabbitmq
startsecs=20
autorestart=unexpected
exitcodes=0,1
stopsignal=KILL
```

So I wonder what is the best way to separate each environment and be able to manage and supervise each service (a container).

**[EDIT My solution inspired by Thomas response]**

each container is run by a .sh script that looking like

*rabbit-integration.py*

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
SERVICE="rabbitmq"
SH_S = "/path/to_shs"
export MY_ENV="integration"
. $SH_S/env_.sh
. $SH_S/utils.sh

SERVICE_ENV=$SERVICE-$MY_ENV
ID_FILE=/tmp/$SERVICE_ENV.name # pid file 

trap stop SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM  # trap signal for calling the stop function
run_rabbitmq
```

*$SH_S/env_.sh* is looking like:

```
# set env variable 
...
case $MONARCH_ENV in
    $INTEGRATION)
       AMQP_PORT="5672"
       AMQP_IP="172.17.42.1"
     ...
    ;;
    $PREPRODUCTION)
       AMQP_PORT="5673"
       AMQP_IP="172.17.42.1"
       ...
        ;;
    $PRODUCTION)
        AMQP_PORT="5674"
        REDIS_IP="172.17.42.1"
        ...
esac
```

*$SH_S/utils.sh* is looking like:

```
#!/bin/bash

function random_name(){
        echo "$SERVICE_ENV-$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)"
}
function stop (){
        echo "stopping docker container..."
        /usr/bin/docker stop `cat $ID_FILE`
}
function run_rabbitmq (){
        # do no daemonize and use stdout
        NAME="$(random_name)"
        echo $NAME > $ID_FILE
        /usr/bin/docker run -i --name "$NAME" -p $AMQP_IP:$AMQP_PORT:5672 -p $AMQP_ADMIN_PORT:15672 -e RABBITMQ_PASS="$AMQP_PASSWORD" myimage-rabbitmq &
        PID=$!
        wait $PID
}
```

At least *myconfig.intergration.conf* is looking like:

```
[program:rabbit-integration]
command=/path/sh_s/rabbit-integration.sh
startsecs=20
priority=90
autorestart=unexpected
exitcodes=0,1
stopsignal=TERM
```

In the case i want use the same container the startup function is looking like:

```
function _run_my_container () {
    NAME="my_container"
    /usr/bin/docker start -i $NAME &
    PID=$!
    wait $PID
    rc=$?
    if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then
       _run_my_container 
    fi
}
```

where

```
function _run_my_container (){
    /usr/bin/docker run -p{} -v{} --name "$NAME" myimage &
    PID=$!
    wait $PID
}
```

Comment: Somewhat orthogonal to what you are specifically asking in this question, but you have you looked at [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?  It allows you to define/administer groups of containers (including links between containers).  Additionally, it allows you to specify [Restart Policies](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) in your configuration, which might handle what you are needing.

Comment: Thanks, I saw it but not found a way to restart a specific service and how to supervise it. We also want to use supervisorctl web interface to be plugged with the exiting monitoring solution.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/dockercraft ... makes a good visual docker manager :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Supervisor requires that the processes it manages do not daemonize, as per its [documentation](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#nondaemonizing-of-subprocesses):

> Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize
>   themselves. Instead, they should run in the foreground. They should
>   not detach from the terminal from which they are started.

This is largely incompatible with Docker, where the containers are subprocesses of *the Docker process* itself (i.e. and hence are not subprocesses of Supervisor).

To be able to use Docker with Supervisor, you could write an equivalent of the [`pidproxy` program](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#pidproxy-program) that works with Docker.

---

But really, the two tools aren't really architected to work together, so you should consider changing one or the other:

- Consider replacing Supervisor with [Docker Compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/) (which is designed to work with Docker)
- Consider replacing Docker with [Rocket](https://github.com/coreos/rkt) (which doesn't have a "master" process)

Comment: Many processes can be run in the foreground therefore they are good candidates to be managed by `supervisor` which is managed by Docker.
E.g. Apache2: `apachectl -D FOREGROUND`, SSH: `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`, Cron: `/usr/sbin/cron -f`

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue that’s the opposite of what was being asked in the question, though (the question is about running a Docker container through Supervisor, but your comment is about running Supervisor in a Docker container).

Answer (score 10):

You need to make sure you use stopsignal=INT in your supervisor config, then exec `docker run` normally.

```
[program:foo]
stopsignal=INT
command=docker -rm run whatever
```

At least this seems to work for me with docker version 1.9.1.

If you run docker from inside a shell script, it is very important that you have `exec` in front of the docker run command, so that `docker run` replaces the shell process and thus receives the SIGINT directly from supervisord.

Comment: Thank you, this is the shortest and most to-the-point advice, and it works for me. I'm using exec in my shell script and it works. I'm using docker --rm -i container, and the log is nicely logged in supervisor logs at /var/log/supervisor.

Comment: Thanks for this.. the exec is the crucial part here, since I'm running a docker from a shell script. Need the exec so that supervisor can shut the process down. Did not need the stopsignal

Comment: This works, but it's not a great answer. Sending a `SIGINT` will likely result in an "ungraceful" shutdown of the process in question.

Answer (score 4):

You can have Docker just not detach and then things work fine. We manage our Docker containers in this way through supervisor. Docker compose is great, but if you're already using Supervisor to manage non-docker things as well, it's nice to keep using it to have all your management in one place. We'll wrap our docker run in a bash script like the following and have supervisor track that, and everything works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash¬
TO_STOP=docker ps | grep $SERVICE_NAME | awk '{ print $1 }'¬
if [$TO_STOP != '']; then¬
    docker stop $SERVICE_NAME¬
fi¬
TO_REMOVE=docker ps -a | grep $SERVICE_NAME | awk '{ print $1 }'¬
if [$TO_REMOVE != '']; then¬
    docker rm $SERVICE_NAME¬
fi¬
¬
docker run -a stdout -a stderr --name="$SERVICE_NAME" \
 --rm $DOCKER_IMAGE:$DOCKER_TAG
```

Comment: This sounds cool, I never even realised supervisor could be used in this manner, what could the supervisor.d/app.conf file look like? How does this replace docker-compose, in a scenario for example when you have many multiple docker-compose files running on a host?

Comment: your `command` in the `app.conf` file would just be running the script containing the above code. To be clear, this is not even close to a complete replacement of `docker-compose` in a situation with any complexity in interaction between containers. I wouldn't recommend doing this except in simple situations where you need to make sure a container is up, but it doesn't need to interact with other containers.

Answer (score 1):

I found that executing `docker run` via supervisor actually works just fine, with a few precautions. The main thing one needs to avoid is allowing supervisord to send a `SIGKILL` to the `docker run` process, which will kill off that process but not the container itself.

For the most part, this can be handled by following the instructions in [Why Your Dockerized Application Isn’t Receiving Signals](https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/). In short, one needs to:

1. Use the `CMD ["/path/to/myapp"]` form (same for `ENTRYPOINT`) instead of the shell form (`CMD /path/to/myapp`).
2. Pass `--init` to `docker run`.
3. If using an `ENTRYPOINT`, ensure its last line calls `exec`, so as to avoid spawning a new process.
4. If the above still isn't working, add a `STOPSIGNAL` to your `Dockerfile`.

Additionally, you'll want to make sure that your `stopwaitsecs` setting in supervisor is greater than the time your process might take to shutdown gracefully when it receives a `SIGTERM` (e.g., [`graceful_timeout`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#graceful-timeout) if using gunicorn).

Here's a sample config to run a gunicorn container:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/usr/bin/docker run --init --rm -i -p 8000:8000 gunicorn
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=31
```